# Angular service method returns 200 code from back end but errors out

Tags: mysql, angular

I'm working with an API that works in the following way...
To fetch data from the back end, you send a POST request and pass it a `reqType='fetch'` together with an SQL statement like so..

```
{
  reqType: 'fetch',
  test: 'SELECT * FROM table_name'
}
```

In my database, I have two tables, one called locations and another countries, where each location belongs to a country. The location table references via a foreign key, the country's name which is set to UNIQUE. Obviously I'm simplifying this.

I then have a service that attempts to fetch all locations from the table based on what country they belong to like so..

```
  public fetchLocations(country) {
    return this.http.post<MyModel>(this.myUrl, {
      reqType: 'fetch',
      test: `SELECT * FROM locations WHERE fk_country='${country}'`
    }).pipe(
      retry(3),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

Inside my client, I access a particular view by a url that looks like this...

```
/section/:countryName/:packageId
```

In my component.ts file, I have imported the `ActivatedRoute` and `ParamMap` from `'@angular/router` and I am then grabbing the values of those params inside `ngOnInit()` like so...

```
this.activeRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
  this.packageId = params.get('packageId');
  this.country = params.get('countryName');
});
```

The `packageId` referes to the id of another table which stores a bunch of other things including a `locationId`. Packages belong to a particular country as well. Thus, I am fetching packages from the database and grabbing the `locationId` from their returned result, which I then want to use to filter through a list of locations returned based on the country. This all works fine. The params are being grabbed successfully.
Using JOINS in not an option for me for reasons I can't get into.

Back to the `component.ts` file...
I have injected my service successfully and in my component I have a method that calls the service method `fetchLocations(country)` to try and get back the relevant locations...

```
private getLocations(country) {
  return this.myService.fetchLocations(country).subscribe(res => {
    this.locations = res;
  }
}
```

After having grabbed the params off the url, I am then calling the method inside `ngOnInit()` and passing in the country.

```
this.getLocations(this.country);
```

However, this returns an error...

```
Backend returned code 200, body was [Object Object]
```

[image: The console log]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: why you use backticks for the query?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, because it is interpolated string in typescript.

Comment: @ABOS I've edited the question and included my console log.

Comment: what is the actual response body from backend? does it have invalid json as the error ?

Comment: No there is no invalid json error. That's literally all I see on my console.

Comment: If you open up the network tab in the browser dev tools and look at the request, you should be able to see the full response from the backend. Can you verify that the string shown in error.text (i.e. "{"data":[{"0": ... ") is valid JSON?